# NetCDF ,time has no units

Tags: python, time, netcdf, dimensions, python-xarray

I have several netcdf files about mean indeces for 2001-2019(each file represents 1 month of the year).The 'time' variable see is of index [0] and has no units (as shown),preventing me from doing plots or statistics relating to time.Is there any way to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Unix this is probably better solved using CDO. Setting the time for one file would be something like this.

```
cdo settime,2001-01-01 in.nc out.nc
```